# Html helper for <input type="file" />

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload, upload, html-helper

Is there a `HTMLHelper` for file upload? Specifically, I am looking for a replace of

```
<input type="file"/>
```

using ASP.NET MVC HTMLHelper.

Or, If I use

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
```

What is the HTML control for the file upload?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

**HTML Upload File ASP MVC 3.**

**Model**: (*Note that FileExtensionsAttribute is available in MvcFutures. It will validate file extensions client side and server side.*)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required, Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FileExtensions(Extensions = "csv", 
             ErrorMessage = "Specify a CSV file. (Comma-separated values)")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML View**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new 
                                       { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
}
```

**Controller action**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Use your file here
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not render a file input `<input type="file" />`, only a text box

Comment: @PauliusZaliaduonis with the line Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FileExtensions the MVC is underlined as red. How do i fix that?

Comment: @pommy Note that FileExtensionsAttribute is available in MvcFutures (As of MVC3). You can use sources from here: [Sources](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetwise-utiltities/source/browse/trunk/DotNetWise.Utilities/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/FileExtensionsAttribute.cs?spec=svn15&r=15)
 
or it is available in .NET Framework 4.5, see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.fileextensionsattribute.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately the FileExtension attribute doesn't seem to work with HttpPostedFileBase type of properties, but rather it seems string only. At least it never did accept pdf as as a valid extension.

Comment: This will add a value attribute (value="") which does not validate as valid HTML5.  value is not valid on input types file and image. I don't see any way of removing the value attribute. It seems to be hard-coded.

Comment: FYI, using HttpPostedFile not HttpPostedFileBase as parameter type in action method cause the binding system to ignore the file.

Comment: @SerjSagan You can create a custom attribute to handle the file extensions for `HttpPostedFileBase`.  See this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536589/asp-net-mvc-3-dataannotations-fileextensionsattribute-not-working#answer-13650754).

Comment: I get 3 textboxes appearing now, and each with a browse button. they are labeled FileName, contenttype and contentlength ???

Comment: @RudyHinojosa , I'm sorry to hear if did not work. Please check that you have valid C# and Razor syntax. Alternatively use plain HTML form and input.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <p>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p> 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Or you could do it properly:

In your HtmlHelper Extension class:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FileFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return helper.FileFor(expression, null);
    }

public static MvcHtmlString FileFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("input");

        var id = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
        builder.GenerateId(id);
        builder.MergeAttribute("name", id);
        builder.MergeAttribute("type", "file");

        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        // Render tag
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

This line:

```
var id = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
```

Generates an id unique to the model, you know in lists and stuff. model[0].Name etc.

Create the correct property in the model:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase NewFile { get; set; }
```

Then you need to make sure your form will send files:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Then here's your helper:

```
@Html.FileFor(x => x.NewFile)
```

Comment: This solution is more eye candy, and keeps me consistent with @Html helper methods .

Answer (score 8):

I had this same question a while back and came across one of Scott Hanselman's posts:

[Implementing HTTP File Upload with ASP.NET MVC including Tests and Mocks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically looking for an implementation of using (Html.BeginForm()), not other variants.

Answer (score 4):

Improved version of Paulius Zaliaduonis' answer:

In order to make the validation work properly I had to change the Model to:

```
public class ViewModel
{
      public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="A header image is required"), FileExtensions(ErrorMessage = "Please upload an image file.")]
        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                if (File != null)
                    return File.FileName;
                else
                    return String.Empty;
            }
        }
}
```

and the view to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new 
                                       { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FileName)
}
```

This is required because what @Serj Sagan wrote about FileExtension attribute working only with strings.

Comment: Can't you merge this answer into Paulius's answer?

Answer (score 2):

To use `BeginForm`, here's the way to use it:

```
 using(Html.BeginForm("uploadfiles", 
"home", FormMethod.POST, new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"type", "file"}})
```

Comment: First you mention how to generate an input element, and now you talk about how to generate a form element? Is this really your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

**Model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{         
    public HttpPostedFileBase File{ get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new 
                                       { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })       
}
```

**Controller action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var postedFile = Request.Files["File"];

       // now you can get and validate the file type:
        var isFileSupported= IsFileSupported(postedFile);

    }
}

public bool IsFileSupported(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                var isSupported = false;

                switch (file.ContentType)
                {

                    case ("image/gif"):
                        isSupported = true;
                        break;

                    case ("image/jpeg"):
                        isSupported = true;
                        break;

                    case ("image/png"):
                        isSupported = true;
                        break;


                    case ("audio/mp3"):  
                        isSupported = true;
                        break;

                    case ("audio/wav"):  
                        isSupported = true;
                        break;                                 
                }

                return isSupported;
            }
```

[List of contentTypes](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Answer (score -2):

This is a little hacky I guess, but it results in the correct validation attributes etc being applied

```
@Html.Raw(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File).ToHtmlString().Replace("type=\"text\"", "type=\"file\""))
```