# Html helper for <input type="file" />

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a HTMLHelper for file upload? Specifically, I am looking for a replace of

```
<input type="file"/>
```

using ASP.NET MVC HTMLHelper.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, none. You have to do it on your own.

Have a look at this article: [A Back To Basics Case Study: Implementing HTTP File Upload with ASP.NET MVC including Tests and Mocks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)